# is there a way for the customer to add a new product to woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an e-commerce website with the woocommerce plugin and I would like to add a new feature that allows the customer to add a new product from the website interface, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plugins there are several options out there. It all depends on the whole concept of your store and the architecture that you have put in place.

1. [Toolset Plugin](https://toolset.com/course-lesson/creating-front-end-forms-for-adding-woocommerce-products/) - you can create frontend forms for adding WooCommerce products
2. [Dokan](https://wedevs.com/dokan) - setup your store as a multivendor. Treat each user as a vendor
3. [WooCommerce User Products](https://booster.io/features/woocommerce-product-by-user/) - create frontend form to add new products by users

I think that you will find a lot of WordPress plugins out there. The only questions is if they are free or not. In my experience, plugins related to WooCommerce most often are not free.